# Display alert when two tables color congruent patterns match

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need help with modifying the code below.

I have two tables,

1. table one has two rows and six columns
2. table two has two rows and six columns with each cell colored either red or yellow creating two congruent shapes.

I want to display an alert when the cells in "table one" match the congruent shapes and their colors of "table two".

*note... You can change the color of the cells by selecting one of the top left buttons (white, yellow or red).

**Is there a way that allows for two solutions that match table two? I've included an image as an example.

[image: two solutions]

```js
jQuery(function() {
  var brush = "white_block";
  jQuery('input.block').on('click', function() {
    brush = jQuery(this).data('brush');
  });

  function cellCheck() {
    var reds = jQuery('#two .red_block').length,
      yellows = jQuery('#two .yellow_block').length,
      cells_colored = reds + yellows,
      cells_total = jQuery('#two td').length;

    //    // condition 1: all colored 
    //    if (cells_colored == cells_total) {
    //      setTimeout(function() {alert("All Colored");}, 100);
    //    }
    //    // condition 2: equal colors
    //    if (reds == yellows) {
    //      setTimeout(function() {alert("Equal colors");}, 100);
    //    }
    //    // condition 3: both conditions
    //    if (cells_colored == cells_total && reds == yellows) {
    //      setTimeout(function() {alert("Finished!");}, 100);
    //    }
  }
  jQuery('td').on('click', function() {
    jQuery(this).removeClass('white_block yellow_block red_block').addClass(brush);
    cellCheck();
  });
});
```

```css
.block {
  border: thin solid #000000;
  width: 59px;
  height: 57px;
}

.white_block {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.red_block {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}

.yellow_block {
  background-color: #FFFF00;
}

table {
  margin: 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <br>Buttons:<br>
  <input type="button" class="block white_block" data-brush="white_block">
  <input type="button" class="block yellow_block" data-brush="yellow_block">
  <input type="button" class="block red_block" data-brush="red_block">
  <br>
  <br> Table One:
  <table id="one">
    <tr>
      <td class="block white_block"></td>
      <td class="block white_block"></td>
      <td class="block white_block"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="block white_block"></td>
      <td class="block white_block"></td>
      <td class="block white_block"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <br> Table Two:
  <table id="two">
    <tr>
      <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="block red_block"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="block red_block"></td>
      <td class="block red_block"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <br>
</body>
```

Comment: Check my answer for easiest solution. :) @TariqSherriff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
jQuery(function() {
  var brush = "white_block";
  jQuery('input.block').on('click', function() {
    brush = jQuery(this).data('brush');
  });

  function cellCheck() {
   $one = $("#one").html().replace(/\s/g,'');
   $two = $("#two").html().replace(/\s/g,'');
   $three = $("#three").html().replace(/\s/g,'');
   if($one === $two){
   alert("match with two");
   }
   if($one === $three){
   alert("match with three");
   }
  }
  jQuery('td').on('click', function() {
    jQuery(this).removeClass('white_block yellow_block red_block').addClass(brush);
    cellCheck();
    getsolution();
  });
 function getsolution(){
  $("#two").clone().each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var newrows = [];
    var firstTr = '';
    var i = 0;
    $this.find("tr").each(function(){
        if(i == 0){
         firstTr = "<tr>"+$(this).html()+"</tr>";
         i++;
         }else{
         $("#three").html("<tr>"+$(this).html()+"</tr>");
         $("#three").append(firstTr);
         }            
    });       
});
}
getsolution();
});
```

```css
.block {
  border: thin solid #000000;
  width: 59px;
  height: 57px;
}

.white_block {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.red_block {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}

.yellow_block {
  background-color: #FFFF00;
}

table {
  margin: 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <br>Buttons:<br>
  <input type="button" class="block white_block" data-brush="white_block">
  <input type="button" class="block yellow_block" data-brush="yellow_block">
  <input type="button" class="block red_block" data-brush="red_block">
  <br>
  <br> Table One:
  <table id="one">
    <tr>
      <td class="block white_block"></td>
      <td class="block white_block"></td>
      <td class="block white_block"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="block white_block"></td>
      <td class="block white_block"></td>
      <td class="block white_block"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <br> Table Two:
  <table id="two">
<tr>
  <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
  <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
  <td class="block red_block"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
  <td class="block red_block"></td>
  <td class="block red_block"></td>
</tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <br>
  Three
  <table id="three">
  </table>
</body>
```

The easiest way to check if two tables html is same. You can take the HTML and replace all the white spaces from them using regex. Now check if two strings are equal.

Comment: Thanks....Is there a way that allows for two solutions that match table two? I've updated the question with an image for an example.

Comment: I don't exactly understand can you please explain? @TariqSherriff

Comment: i just re-updated the picture. table 2 is compared to either solutions for table 1. I hope that makes sense

Comment: Yes that makes sense but how exactly do you want the 2nd solution to be? The reverse of first solution?

Comment: yes that would ok. in the image example that I provided there would be a total of 4 different solutions I guess. but I don't want to ask for too much. Reverse would be ok...thank you for your help and patience

Comment: I have updated my code for reverse and it works fine. Please check if that's ok for you? @TariqSherriff

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate your support.

Comment: Welcome brother glad to help. :) @TariqSherriff

Answer (score 1):

Please use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/96oa88eu/46/)

```js
jQuery(function() {
  var brush = "white_block";
  jQuery('input.block').on('click', function() {
    brush = jQuery(this).data('brush');
  });
 
 var arr_t_one = [];
  var arr_t_two = [];
  var s = 0;
  function cellCheck() {
    var reds = jQuery('#two .red_block').length,
      yellows = jQuery('#two .yellow_block').length,
      cells_colored = reds + yellows,
      cells_total = jQuery('#two td').length;
      arr_t_one = [];
      arr_t_two = [];
   $( "#one td" ).each(function( index ) {
     arr_t_one.push($( this ).attr('class') );
   });
      $( "#two td" ).each(function( index ) {
     arr_t_two.push($( this ).attr('class') );
   });
      var is_same = (arr_t_one.length == arr_t_two.length) && arr_t_one.every(function(element, index) {
        return element === arr_t_two[index]; 
     });
      var is_not_same = (arr_t_one.length == arr_t_two.length) && arr_t_one.every(function(element, index) {
        return element !== arr_t_two[index]; 
     });
    if(is_same==true)
     setTimeout(function() {alert("Exact Match");}, 100);
    if(is_not_same==true)
      setTimeout(function() {alert("Not matched Exactly");}, 100); 
  }
  
  jQuery('td').on('click', function() {
    jQuery(this).removeClass('white_block yellow_block red_block').addClass(brush);
    if(brush!='white_block'){
      cellCheck();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.block {
  border: thin solid #000000;
  width: 59px;
  height: 57px;
}

.white_block {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.red_block {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}

.yellow_block {
  background-color: #FFFF00;
}

table {
  margin: 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <br>Buttons:<br>
  <input type="button" class="block white_block" data-brush="white_block">
  <input type="button" class="block yellow_block" data-brush="yellow_block">
  <input type="button" class="block red_block" data-brush="red_block">
  <br>
  <br> Table One:
  <table id="one">
    <tr>
      <td class="block white_block"></td>
      <td class="block white_block"></td>
      <td class="block white_block"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="block white_block"></td>
      <td class="block white_block"></td>
      <td class="block white_block"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <br> Table Two:
  <table id="two">
    <tr>
      <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="block red_block"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="block red_block"></td>
      <td class="block red_block"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <br>
</body>
```

I have checked the **class name for exact match**..

Comment: Thanks....Is there a way that allows for two solutions that match table two? I've updated the question with an image for an example.

Comment: You need exact opposite table for solution 2 ? Am i right ?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check and let me know if it is worked or not.

Comment: fair enough, however spotted some flaw, after a "not exact match" if you blank some squares it keeps saying the same message despite the blanks